# Retrieving data URL stored in session variable using PHP in an apache web server on a linux virtual machine

Tags: php, azure, apache

I have a form which is processed by php with the code i will provide below. on my local machine it works perfectly and the avatar is created and can be retrieved by the session variable for the navbar however not when i transferred the files to the virtual machine.

to process the form i have this:

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $colour = $_POST['colour'];
        $eyes = $_POST['eyes'];
        $mouth = $_POST['mouth'];
    
        $_SESSION['registered'] = true;
        $colour_path = $colour . '.png';
        $eyes_path = $eyes . '.png';
        $mouth_path = $mouth . '.png';
    
        // Create the image objects from the PNG files
        $colour_img = imagecreatefrompng($colour_path);
        $eyes_img = imagecreatefrompng($eyes_path);
        $mouth_img = imagecreatefrompng($mouth_path);
    
    // Create a blank image to hold the avatar
        $avatar = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($colour_img), imagesy($colour_img));
    
        // Set the background color of the avatar to the selected color
        $color_rgb = imagecolorallocate($avatar, 0, 0, 255); // replace with the RGB values of the selected color
        imagefill($avatar, 0, 0, $color_rgb);
    
        // Copy the eyes and mouth onto the avatar
        imagecopy($avatar, $colour_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($colour_img), imagesy($colour_img));
        imagecopy($avatar, $eyes_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($eyes_img), imagesy($eyes_img));
        imagecopy($avatar, $mouth_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($mouth_img), imagesy($mouth_img));
    
        // Output the image data to a string
        ob_start();
        imagepng($avatar);
        $image_data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    
        imagedestroy($avatar);
    
        // Encode the image data as a data URL
        $data_url = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image_data);
    
        // Set the data URL as a session variable
        $_SESSION['avatar'] = $data_url;
        
        // Redirect to index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

And the navbar script to display the avatar:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['registered'])): ?>
        <div class="avatar-navbar">
          <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar']; ?>">
        </div>
```

I tried changing file permissions to 644 and adjusting the file path from the root directory. i am fairly sure the issue is with the data URL is saved in the session variable and thus the retrieval of that data URL. is it possible to fix this for my web server on my virtual machine. also i have installed the php GD library on apache and restarted it.

Comment: Error Log! Did you look at it yet?

Comment: I have tried inspecting the the web page yes if that is what you are referring to. Ive just realised you are probably referring to an error log you view from the virtual machine, no I haven't looked at that I will try figure out how to now. This is my first web development project and first time using a web server!

Comment: I am getting 4 errors to do with the imagesy(), imagecopy(), imagesx(), and imagepng() functions. They are receiving a boolean value instead of an image resource apparently. Even more confusing as to why it works on my machine but not the apache webserver

Comment: Are the versions of PHP different on these 2 environments? What are the versions? And what EXACTLY are these error messages

Comment: Seems that the image aren't created, so you have boolean false. Check that $colour_path is a real path to the png ( _$colour_path = $colour . '.png';_ ) and in the same dir as the basedir of the script and the dir is at least 750 for the user/group running the vhost